# Is there an instruction to "pack" a register in amd64 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

amd64 offers a lot of obscure hardware shortcuts. What I have is `0xff00ff00ff00ff00`, what I want is `0xffffffff00000000`, or even `0x00000000ffffffff`. Digging though AMD's [manuals](http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/developer-guides-manuals/) reveals `pshufb`, but the manual is vague in its operation.
My question is, is there a instruction(not a software implementation) that performs the operation described above?

Comment: Do you always want to move around whole bytes?  If yes, SSSE3 `pshufb` is the way to go.  If you want to pack with bit granularity, use BMI2 `pext` if available.  (See [another answer I just wrote using pext/pdep](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36951611/224132).)  BTW, Intel's insn ref manual is nice.  It has good diagrams for instructions that need them.  See the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links to it and Intel's intrinsics guide.

Comment: To clarify, you want to shuffle a general-purpose register, as opposed to a vector-register? You might want to have a look at the `pext/pdep`-instructions, added in `BMI2`.

Comment: @EOF Since I am using pure assembly, I can just move the values around if it's needed. But thanks for the information!

Comment: `movq xmm, r64` or vice versa isn't totally free.  `pext` and then optionally `shl` to pack towards the high half of a register would be cheaper than movq/pshufd/movq back to an integer reg.  `pext` shuffle constants can be loaded with `mov r64, imm64`, but `pshufb` constants are 16B.  However, if you can vectorize your algorithm to do the whole thing in xmm registers, esp. with two 64b elements at once, then `pshufb` is great.

Comment: See Agner Fog's guides / insn tables, and other stuff (like Intel's optimization manuals) in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pshufb`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PSHUFB.html) is probably the instruction you want.

It takes two MMX / XMM registers as arguments. The first one is the data to shuffle; the second one (the "control mask") controls how it is shuffled.

The data in each register is broken down into bytes. For each byte of the output, the processor uses the corresponding byte in the control mask to decide how to set it:

- If the high bit (`0x80`) of the mask byte is set, the result for this byte is zero.
- Otherwise, the lower half of the mask byte is used as an index into the input bytes. For instance, if the mask byte is `0x03`, the third byte of the input is used for this byte of the output.

By way of example, a control mask of `0x0f0e0d0c0b0a09080706050403020100` will reverse the bytes in a register.

Note that if you're just working with normal integer registers, getting the data in and out of the appropriate registers may be awkward. Using compiler intrinsics may make this easier.

Comment: I think `0x0f0e...00` is the identity mask (every element is unchanged).  The high byte is the first byte, because you wrote it as one large 128bit number.  With each byte separately, in little-endian order,  `0x0f, 0x0e, ..., 0x00` is the byte-reverse mask.

Answer (score 0):

In this git is complete code for sorting nibbles: https://github.com/regehr/nibble-sort/blob/master/scotty.c

```
#include "nibble.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>

/*
  5.8.5 Packed Shuffle Bytes
  PSHUFB Permutes each byte in place, according to
  a shuffle control mask. The least significant three or
  four bits of each shuffle control byte of the control mask form the shuffle
  index. The shuffle
  mask is unaffected. If the most significant bit
  (bit 7) of a shuffle control byte is set, the
  constant zero is written in the result byte
*/

// typedef unsigned char uchar

// extern const int BUFSIZE;

/* compile with:
 gcc -std=gnu99 -march=native -fbranch-probabilities -ftracer
 -fprefetch-loop-arrays -O3
*/

void nibble_sort_scotty(unsigned long *buf);

static inline unsigned long create_mask(char amount, char type, char location) {
  unsigned long all = type;
  int i;

  switch (amount) {
  case 0:
    return 0;
  default:
    for (i = 0; i < amount - 1; i++) {
      all = ((all << 4) | type);
    }
    return all << location;
  }
}

static inline unsigned long write_new(__m128i read) {
  unsigned long write = 0;
  int i;
  unsigned int where = 64;
  unsigned int pulled;
  /* ignore zeros saves on loop iterations */

  pulled = _mm_extract_epi8(read, 15);
  where = where - (pulled * 4);
  write |= create_mask(pulled, 0xF, where);

  pulled = _mm_extract_epi8(read, 14);
  where = where - (pulled * 4);
  write |= create_mask(pulled, 0xE, where);

  pulled = _mm_extract_epi8(read, 13);
  where = where - (pulled * 4);
  write |= create_mask(pulled, 0xD, where);

  pulled = _mm_extract_epi8(read, 12);
  where = where - (pulled * 4);
  write |= create_mask(pulled, 0xC, where);

  pulled = _mm_extract_epi8(read, 11);
  where = where - (pulled * 4);
  write |= create_mask(pulled, 0xB, where);

  pulled = _mm_extract_epi8(read, 10);
  where = where - (pulled * 4);
  write |= create_mask(pulled, 0xA, where);

  pulled = _mm_extract_epi8(read, 9);
  where = where - (pulled * 4);
  write |= create_mask(pulled, 9, where);

  pulled = _mm_extract_epi8(read, 8);
  where = where - (pulled * 4);
  write |= create_mask(pulled, 8, where);

  pulled = _mm_extract_epi8(read, 7);
  where = where - (pulled * 4);
  write |= create_mask(pulled, 7, where);

  pulled = _mm_extract_epi8(read, 6);
  where = where - (pulled * 4);
  ;
  write |= create_mask(pulled, 6, where);

  pulled = _mm_extract_epi8(read, 5);
  where = where - (pulled * 4);
  ;
  write |= create_mask(pulled, 5, where);

  pulled = _mm_extract_epi8(read, 4);
  where = where - (pulled * 4);
  ;
  write |= create_mask(pulled, 4, where);

  pulled = _mm_extract_epi8(read, 3);
  where = where - (pulled * 4);
  ;
  write |= create_mask(pulled, 3, where);

  pulled = _mm_extract_epi8(read, 2);
  where = where - (pulled * 4);
  ;
  write |= create_mask(pulled, 2, where);

  pulled = _mm_extract_epi8(read, 1);
  where = where - (pulled * 4);
  ;
  write |= create_mask(pulled, 1, where);

  return write;
}

void nibble_sort_scotty(unsigned long *temp) {
  __builtin_prefetch(temp, 1, 3);
  unsigned long sorted;
  __m128i all = {0};
  __m128i zero = {0};

  int i, j;
  int word_holder;
  unsigned long *buf = temp;
  /* NOTES:
     epi32 extract so one can preserver the "higher" bits of 'all'
     if we didnt we'd be slamming 0's into all ruining the count
  */
  for (j = 0; j < 1024; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      /* todo mm extract the byte then nibble shift */
      if (*buf == 0)
        break;

      switch (((*buf) & 0xf)) {
      case 0:
        // word_holder = _mm_extract_epi32(all, 0);
        // all = _mm_insert_epi32(all, word_holder + 0x1, 0);
        break;
      case 1:
        word_holder = _mm_extract_epi32(all, 0);
        all = _mm_insert_epi32(all, (word_holder + 0x100), 0);
        break;
      case 2:
        word_holder = _mm_extract_epi32(all, 0);
        all = _mm_insert_epi32(all, (word_holder + 0x10000), 0);
        break;
      case 3:
        word_holder = _mm_extract_epi32(all, 0);
        all = _mm_insert_epi32(all, (word_holder + 0x1000000), 0);
        break;
      case 4:
        word_holder = _mm_extract_epi32(all, 1);
        all = _mm_insert_epi32(all, (word_holder + 0x1), 1);
        break;
      case 5:
        word_holder = _mm_extract_epi32(all, 1);
        all = _mm_insert_epi32(all, (word_holder + 0x100), 1);
        break;
      case 6:
        word_holder = _mm_extract_epi32(all, 1);
        all = _mm_insert_epi32(all, (word_holder + 0x10000), 1);
        break;
      case 7:
        word_holder = _mm_extract_epi32(all, 1);
        all = _mm_insert_epi32(all, (word_holder + 0x1000000), 1);
        break;
      case 8:
        word_holder = _mm_extract_epi32(all, 2);
        all = _mm_insert_epi32(all, (word_holder + 0x1), 2);
        break;
      case 9:
        word_holder = _mm_extract_epi32(all, 2);
        all = _mm_insert_epi32(all, (word_holder + 0x100), 2);
        break;
      case 0xA:
        word_holder = _mm_extract_epi32(all, 2);
        all = _mm_insert_epi32(all, (word_holder + 0x10000), 2);
        break;
      case 0xB:
        word_holder = _mm_extract_epi32(all, 2);
        all = _mm_insert_epi32(all, (word_holder + 0x1000000), 2);
        break;
      case 0xC:
        word_holder = _mm_extract_epi32(all, 3);
        all = _mm_insert_epi32(all, (word_holder + 0x1), 3);
        break;
      case 0xD:
        word_holder = _mm_extract_epi32(all, 3);
        all = _mm_insert_epi32(all, (word_holder + 0x100), 3);
        break;
      case 0xE:
        word_holder = _mm_extract_epi32(all, 3);
        all = _mm_insert_epi32(all, (word_holder + 0x10000), 3);
        break;
      case 0xF:
        word_holder = _mm_extract_epi32(all, 3);
        all = _mm_insert_epi32(all, (word_holder + 0x1000000), 3);
        break;
      default:
        __builtin_abort();
      }
      *buf >>= 4;
    }
    __builtin_prefetch((buf + 1), 1, 3);
    *buf = write_new(all);
    all = zero;
    buf++;
  }
}

/*
int main(void)
{
        //  unsigned long test = 0xc67b1f9a06cac113;
        unsigned long test = 0x728dc8ba40781809;//0xfbbbc9741902c44c;// at 0 to
sort to fcccbbb997444210
        nibble_sort_scotty(&test);
        printf("%lx\n", test);
}
*/
```

set up the **shuffle control mask** in *mm2* / *xmm2*