# Implementation of bit rotate operators using SIMD in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, bitwise-operators, simd

I know that StackOverflow is not meant for asking code to other persons, but let me speak.

I am trying to implement some AES functions in CUDA C++ device code. While trying to implement the left bytewise rotate operator, I was disconcerted to see that there was no native SIMD intrisic for that. So I began a naive implementation, but....it's huge, and while I haven't tried it yet, it just won't be fast because of the expensive unpacking/packing... So, is there a mean to do a per byte bit rotate operation that's at least *somewhat* efficient ?

Here's the code if you wan't to have a look.

```
__inline__ __device__ uint32_t per_byte_bit_left_rotate(uint32_t input, uint8_t amount) {
return ((((input & 0xFF) >> 0) << amount) | (((input & 0xFF) >> 0) >> 7) & ~0x100) << 0 |
     ((((input & 0xFF00) >> 8) << amount) | ((input & 0xFF00 >> 8) >> 7) & ~0x100) << 8 |
     ((((input & 0xFF0000) >> 16) << amount) | ((input & 0xFF0000 >> 16) >> 7) & ~0x100) << 16 |
     ((((input & 0xFF000000) >> 24) << amount) | ((input & 0xFF000000 >> 24) >> 7) & ~0x100) << 24; } // The XORs are for clearing the old 7th bit who is getting pushed to the next byte of the intermediate int
```

Comment: I don't think your XOR works.  It will set the bit if it was zero to start with.  You need an AND to unconditionally clear a bit.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't catch that, I'm going to edit it. As I said, this wasn't even compiled yet, just though about

Comment: I *think* you need `& ~0x100`.  or just `& 0xFF` since you're shifting everything to the low byte.  AND with `0x100` would zero everything *except* that bit.

Comment: Wanting to go too fast in my edit I guess. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rotate count is the same for all elements, right?

Shift the whole input left and right, and then **AND those with masks that zero all the bits that crossed a byte boundary**, for all 4 bytes in one AND.  I think `amount` is always a compile-time constant in AES, so you don't have to worry about the runtime cost of generating the masks on the fly.  Just let the compiler do it.  (IDK CUDA, but this appears to be the same problem as writing a [SWAR bit-hack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWAR) with 32-bit integers for normal C++)

This is based on the usual [`(x << count) | (x >> (32-count))` rotate idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/best-practices-for-circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c), with masking and a different right-shift count to make it into separate 8-bit rotates.

```
inline
uint32_t per_byte_bit_left_rotate(uint32_t input, unsigned amount)
{
    // With constant amount, the left/right masks are constants
    uint32_t rmask = 0xFF >> ((8 - amount) & 7);
    rmask = (rmask<<24 | rmask<<16 | rmask<<8 | rmask);
    uint32_t lmask = ~rmask;

    uint32_t lshift = input << amount;
    lshift &= lmask;
    if (amount == 1) {  // special case left-shift by 1 using an in-lane add instead of shift&mask
        lshift = __vadd4(input, input);
    }
    uint32_t rshift = input >> ((8 - amount) & 7);
    rshift &= rmask;

    uint32_t rotated = lshift | rshift;
    return rotated;
}
```

It might be even more efficient to mask the input one way before shifting, and mask the output after shifting (`(in&lmask)<<amount | ((in>>(8-amount))&rmask)`, with a different lmask).  NVidia hardware is in-order superscalar, and [shifts have limited throughput](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/38864352#38864352).  Doing it that way would be more likely to execute as two an independent shift+mask pairs.

(This doesn't try to avoid C++ UB with amount>=32.  See [Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/best-practices-for-circular-shift-rotate-operations-in-c).  In this case, I think changing to `lshift = input << (amount & 7)` would do the trick.

To test that this compiles efficiently, I looked at the [clang `-O3` asm output](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0Ainline%0Auint32_t+per_byte_bit_left_rotate(uint32_t+input,+unsigned+amount)%0A%7B%0A++++//+With+constant+amount,+the+masks+are+constants%0A++++uint32_t+rmask+%3D+0xFF+%3E%3E+((8+-+amount)+%26+7)%3B%0A++++rmask+%3D+(rmask%3C%3C24+%7C+rmask%3C%3C16+%7C+rmask%3C%3C8+%7C+rmask)%3B%0A++++uint32_t+lmask+%3D+~rmask%3B%0A%0A++++uint32_t+lshift+%3D+input+%3C%3C+amount%3B%0A++++uint32_t+rshift+%3D+input+%3E%3E+((8+-+amount)+%26+7)%3B%0A%0A++++uint32_t+rotated+%3D+(lshift%26lmask)+%7C+(rshift%26rmask)%3B%0A++++return+rotated%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Auint32_t+rol7(uint32_t+a)+%7B%0A++++return+per_byte_bit_left_rotate(a,+7)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Auint32_t+test_rol()+%7B%0A++++return+per_byte_bit_left_rotate(0x02ffff04,+0)%3B++//+yup,+returns+the+input+with+count%3D0%0A%7D%0A%0Auint32_t+test2_rol()+%7B%0A++++return+per_byte_bit_left_rotate(0x02f73804,+4)%3B++//+yup,+swaps+nibbles%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang400,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-O3+-Wall',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+4.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:99.99999999999999,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) for x86-64 with a constant `amount`.  The Godbolt compiler explorer has compilers for various architectures (not CUDA though), so click that link and flip to ARM, MIPS or PowerPC if you can read those asm languages more easily than x86.

```
uint32_t rol7(uint32_t a) {
    return per_byte_bit_left_rotate(a, 7);
}
    mov     eax, edi
    shl     eax, 7
    shr     edi
    and     eax, -2139062144   # 0x80808080
    and     edi, 2139062143    # 0x7F7F7F7F
    lea     eax, [rdi + rax]   # ADD = OR when no bits intersect
    ret
```

Perfect, exactly what I hoped for.

A couple test cases:

```
uint32_t test_rol() {
    return per_byte_bit_left_rotate(0x02ffff04, 0);
}
    // yup, returns the input with count=0
    // return 0x2FFFF04


uint32_t test2_rol() {
    return per_byte_bit_left_rotate(0x02f73804, 4);
}
    // yup, swaps nibbles
    // return 0x207F8340
```

This is the same kind of thing you need to do for 8-bit shifts with x86 SSE2 / AVX2, because the smallest shift granularity the hardware supports is 16-bit.

Comment: Actually, the "CUDA" part of my question is because CUDA supports some SIMD intrisics, but it's fine to do without it, all the basic operations being obviously defined in SASS (the object level instruction set used by CUDA devices). The >= 32 bit UB won't really matter, as nowhere is AES it is invoked

Comment: @Sachiko.Shinozaki: Ah I see.  http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SIMD.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SIMD.  Stuff like half-word or byte-element add in lanes inside a 32-bit integer.  For a left-shift by 1, you could use `__vadd4` instead of shift/mask.  (`x+x = x<<1`)

Comment: I actually find myself very dumbfounded on this one, but anyway, error are there so you can learn on them. And my very respects, not knowing CUDA and yet digging through the math intrisics to help me. Thanks infinitly. And thanks for introducing me to the world of SWAR. While I do some basic assembly , I don't have real references to the assembly world to learn more advanced idioms.

Comment: @Sachiko.Shinozaki: answering questions is a great way to learn about new stuff that I've been meaning to get around to learning about :)  I was curious what kind of stuff CUDA supported.

Comment: @Sachiko.Shinozaki: For more SWAR / bithack stuff, see https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html.  There's some neat stuff, but a lot of it is things that are better done with intrinsics these days (e.g. popcnt or tzcnt).  Or SIMD intrinsics for a zero byte in a word.  Still, it's very cool to see how you could implement `popcnt` by masking and shifting so you can do 16 1-bit additions that don't carry into each other, then 8 2-bit additions, etc.  See also http://www.hackersdelight.org/

Comment: Thanks a 3rd time. I can now return wander the plain of the project i'm into right now. As I am still a hobbyist (waiting the age to being a student) those kind of ressources really help me out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152926/discussion-between-sachiko-shinozaki-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: @Sachiko: But I think I've picked up more of this kind of stuff from manually vectorizing stuff with SSE / AVX than from bit-hack web sites.  e.g. one I'm quite proud of uses x86's `pdep` / `pext` instructions to generate shuffle masks for a vector shuffle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932240/avx2-what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-pack-left-based-on-a-mask.  If you're interested in x86 asm, or tuning for x86 at all, see the links in the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info), especially http://agner.org/optimize/.

Answer (score 6):

CUDA has a `__byte_perm()` intrinsic that maps directly to the `PRMT` instruction at the machine code (SASS) level, which is a byte-wise permute instruction. It can be used to efficiently extract and merge bytes. To affect a byte-wise left rotation, we can double up each byte, shift byte-pairs by the desired amount, then extract and merge the four high-bytes of the byte pairs.

For byte-wise rotation, we only need the lowest three bits of the shift amount, as a rotation by `s` is the same as a rotation by `s mod 8`. For efficiency, it is best to avoid integer types comprising fewer than 32 bits, as C++ semantics require integer types narrower than `int` to be widened to `int` before use in expressions. This can and does incur conversion overhead on many architectures, including GPUs.

The throughput of the `PRMT` instruction is architecture dependent, so the use of `__byte_perm()` may lead to code that is faster or slower than use of the  classical SIMD-in-a-register method demonstrated in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45901127/780717), so be sure to benchmark in the context of your use case prior to deployment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

__device__ uint32_t per_byte_bit_left_rotate (uint32_t input, uint32_t amount)
{
     uint32_t l = __byte_perm (input, 0, 0x1100) << (amount & 7);
     uint32_t h = __byte_perm (input, 0, 0x3322) << (amount & 7);
     return __byte_perm (l, h, 0x7531);
}

__global__ void rotl_kernel (uint32_t input, uint32_t amount, uint32_t *res)
{
    *res = per_byte_bit_left_rotate (input, amount);
}

uint32_t ref_per_byte_bit_left_rotate (uint32_t input, uint32_t amount)
{
   int s = amount & 7;
   uint8_t b0 = (input >>  0) & 0xff;
   uint8_t b1 = (input >>  8) & 0xff;
   uint8_t b2 = (input >> 16) & 0xff;
   uint8_t b3 = (input >> 24) & 0xff;
   b0 = s ? ((b0 << s) | (b0 >> (8 - s))) : b0;
   b1 = s ? ((b1 << s) | (b1 >> (8 - s))) : b1;
   b2 = s ? ((b2 << s) | (b2 >> (8 - s))) : b2;
   b3 = s ? ((b3 << s) | (b3 >> (8 - s))) : b3;
   return (b3 << 24) | (b2 << 16) | (b1 << 8) | (b0 << 0);
}

// Fixes via: Greg Rose, KISS: A Bit Too Simple. http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/007
static unsigned int z=362436069,w=521288629,jsr=362436069,jcong=123456789;
#define znew (z=36969*(z&0xffff)+(z>>16))
#define wnew (w=18000*(w&0xffff)+(w>>16))
#define MWC  ((znew<<16)+wnew)
#define SHR3 (jsr^=(jsr<<13),jsr^=(jsr>>17),jsr^=(jsr<<5)) /* 2^32-1 */
#define CONG (jcong=69069*jcong+13579)                     /* 2^32 */
#define KISS ((MWC^CONG)+SHR3)

// Macro to catch CUDA errors in CUDA runtime calls
#define CUDA_SAFE_CALL(call)                                          \
do {                                                                  \
    cudaError_t err = call;                                           \
    if (cudaSuccess != err) {                                         \
        fprintf (stderr, "Cuda error in file '%s' in line %i : %s.\n",\
                 __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString(err) );       \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                           \
    }                                                                 \
} while (0)

// Macro to catch CUDA errors in kernel launches
#define CHECK_LAUNCH_ERROR()                                          \
do {                                                                  \
    /* Check synchronous errors, i.e. pre-launch */                   \
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();                             \
    if (cudaSuccess != err) {                                         \
        fprintf (stderr, "Cuda error in file '%s' in line %i : %s.\n",\
                 __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString(err) );       \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                           \
    }                                                                 \
    /* Check asynchronous errors, i.e. kernel failed (ULF) */         \
    err = cudaThreadSynchronize();                                    \
    if (cudaSuccess != err) {                                         \
        fprintf (stderr, "Cuda error in file '%s' in line %i : %s.\n",\
                 __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString( err) );      \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                           \
    }                                                                 \
} while (0)

int main (void)
{
    uint32_t arg, ref, res = 0, *res_d = 0;
    uint32_t shft;

    CUDA_SAFE_CALL (cudaMalloc ((void**)&res_d, sizeof(*res_d)));
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        arg  = KISS;
        shft = KISS;
        ref = ref_per_byte_bit_left_rotate (arg, shft);
        rotl_kernel <<<1,1>>>(arg, shft, res_d);
        CHECK_LAUNCH_ERROR();
        CUDA_SAFE_CALL (cudaMemcpy (&res, res_d, sizeof (res), 
                                    cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        if (res != ref) {
            printf ("!!!! arg=%08x shft=%d  res=%08x  ref=%08x\n", 
                    arg, shft, res, ref);
        }
    }
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL (cudaFree (res_d));
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL (cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Well...I hadn't thought a second that __byte_perm() could be used to select some bytes, I always found that intrisic useless in some sense (which is probably why it's speed is not consistent, as graphics must not use a lot if it I guess). Thank for lightning my path. But, the bX variables, being uint8_t, don't they get first casted to char, then re-casted to int in the return line ? ANDs could be efficient to mask some data, couldn't it ? (assuming some more register pressure)

Comment: @Sachiko.Shinozaki the `b?` variables only occur in the *reference* implementation which was written for functionality, not performance. Other implementations of the reference function are possible, of course. `__byte_perm()` is useful to shift/rotate by multiples of 8 bits, swap bytes, splat bytes across a 32-bit word etc. The CUDA compiler will sometimes generate the `PRMT` instruction, but not often, from my observations. I don't do graphics, so can't speak to it's utility there.

Comment: We can just guess that the compiler "understand" the logic of `__byte_perm()` and uses according PTX/SASS based on the architecture / pipeline use ..? Nvidia doesn't reveal that kind of stuff, so we can just guess.

Comment: @Sachiko.Shinozaki `__byte_perm()` translates into `PRMT`, it is an *intrinsic*. If skeptical, you can always double check with `cuobjdump -dump-sass`. When I stated that the CUDA compiler will sometimes use `PRMT`, I was referring to those instances *not* originating from explicit us of `__byte_perm()`, e.g. a shift by 8. Sorry if that wasn't clear.