# Analyzing results of comparision in AVX2

Tags: assembly, sse, avx2

I'm trying to optimize code with AVX2 assembly.
At one point I need to compare the result of computation with the threshold and write 0 or 255 byte to
output.
I compare with

```
VCMPPD ymm2,ymm1 (values here),ymm4 (thresholds here),1
```

Then, ymm2 holds 4 QUADWORDS 0 and 0xFF. Ideally would be to shrink it all to 4 byte in EAX.
But now, I'm doing 4 VPTEST operations and several conditional jumps to form the output. This slows down the performance significantly.

Question: how to get and use the result of comparison with AVX2 effectively?

Comment: Is `VPMOVMSKB eax, ymm2` what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for `vmovmskpd eax, ymm2` ([manual entry](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movmskpd)) to get a 4-bit bitmap which you can then analyze with integer instructions like `test eax,eax`. or `cmp al, 0xf` to check if *all* elements were true, or even as an index for a jump table like `jmp [table + rax*8]` if you need finer detail of which elements were true.

You could of course use `vpmovmskb` if you actually *want* 8 identical bits from each vector element, one from each byte.

If you didn't already know about `movmskps/pd` and so on, I'd suggest Agner Fog's optimization guide: he has a chapter about SIMD.  https://agner.org/optimize/.  vector -> bitmap is one of x86's best features.

Comment: While this is certainly correct, often the thing the SIMD programmer should really be asking is why the data needs to be moved  back to the condition registers / scalar domain in the first place? If possible, it may be preferable to use the vector compare results as is in a branch free vector algorithm downstream and skip the branchiness all together.  However, this would mean asking the age old question ”What are you really trying to do?”, which 3 years after the fact seems unlikely to bear fruit.

Comment: @IanOllmann: Yeah, looking at this again, it's not clear what they're really trying to do.  Maybe they can just pack 8 vectors of qword compare results down one of bytes using `vpacksswb` which preserves the high bit of each word (and keeps them as 0 / -1).  (And an eventual byte-shuffle or something to rearrange, since in-lane pack instructions work on the 128-bit halves separately.)

Comment: Or at least a scalar lookup table of data based on the 4-bit mask, such as a shuffle-control vector for `vpermpd` or something, if left-packing the original elements.  (See [AVX2 what is the most efficient way to pack left based on a mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36932240) - 4 elements is few enough for a LUT of shuffle vectors to be good, unlike with 8 elements in a `__m256`.)  IDK why I only mentioned indexing a jump table when I wrote this answer!