# C/SIMD - creating an 'immediate array'; an array that returns immediate values?

Tags: c, simd, sse, lookup-tables, immediate-operand

```
#include <immintrin.h>

static const unsigned char LUT[16] = { 0xE4, 0x24, 0x34, 0x04, 
                                       0x38, 0x08, 0x0C, 0x00, 
                                       0x39, 0x09, 0x0D, 0x01, 
                                       0x0E, 0x02, 0x03, 0x00 };

int main( ) {
    float input[4] = { -1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, -4.0f };
    float output[4] = {0};

    __m128 data = _mm_loadu_ps( input );
    __m128 mmask = _mm_cmpge_ps( data, _mm_setzero_ps( ) );
    int shufctr = _mm_movemask_ps( mmask );

    __m128 res = _mm_shuffle_ps( data, data, LUT[shufctr] );
    _mm_storeu_ps( output, res );
}
```

I am meaning to use code similar to the above to left pack an array of floats that pass the compare into another but it's returning the error
'**the last argument must be an 8-bit immediate.**' How can I achieve this?

Comment: See [AVX2 what is the most efficient way to pack left based on a mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36932240) (which mentions the SSSE3 way to start with, which is this with `_mm_shuffle_epi8`, which doesn't efficiently extend to more elements per vector).

Comment: "immediate" means a constant embedded in the machine code.  The only way you could literally make a lookup table for it would be with self-modifying machine code, which would cause a "pipeline nuke" (`machine_clears.smc`) every time the function ran, making it slower than scalar.

Comment: thanks for the clarification Peter, i'll look into doing it the SSSE3 way.

Answer (score 2):

Function [`_mm_shuffle_ps()`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_shuffle_ps&expand=6372) requires an unsigned 8-bit immediate as the third parameter; that means that the third parameter must be a compile-time known integer constant:

```c
__m128 res = _mm_shuffle_ps(data, data, LUT[shufctr]); // WRONG
__m128 res = _mm_shuffle_ps(data, data, foo()); // WRONG
__m128 res = _mm_shuffle_ps(data, data, bar); // WRONG
__m128 res = _mm_shuffle_ps(data, data, 250); // CORRECT
```

A possible (not-so-great) approach to solve the problem:

```c
...
int shufctr = _mm_movemask_ps(mmask);
__m128 res;

if (shufctr == 0) {
  res = _mm_shuffle_ps(data, data, 0xE4); // LUT[0] == 0xE4
}
else if (...) {
  ...
}
...
```

---

EDIT (adding information given by user Peter Cordes in a comment):

You may also take a look at SSSE3 `pshufb` or AVX1 `vpermilps`. Both of these instructions use a shuffle-control vector (runtime variable) rather than an immediate constant that must be embedded in the instruction stream. So you can use the `movemask` result to look up from a table of shuffle control vectors. SSE2 doesn't have any variable-control shuffles, only variable-count bit-shifts.

Comment: is there no way of defining a compile-time lookup table/array of sorts that will let me do what I'm trying to do without endless if elses?

Comment: @Timothys: Yes, with SSSE3 `pshufb` or AVX1 `vpermilps`.  Both of those use a shuffle-control *vector* (runtime variable) rather than an immediate constant that must be embedded in the instruction stream.  So you can use the movemask result to look up from a table of shuffle control vectors.  SSE2 doesn't have any variable-control shuffles, only variable-count bit-shifts.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the additional info, I've added your comment in my answer.