# How to pack __m128i elements using masks?

Tags: simd, avx

I have the following:

```
int j0 = 190;
int j1 = 191;
int j2 = 192;
int j3 = 193;
__m128i jv = _mm_set_epi32(j3, j2, j1, j0);
__m256d rij = _mm256_set_pd(2.8, 1.8, 2.1, 3.4);
__m256d sij = _mm256_set1_pd(2.5);
__m256d mask = sij - rij;
```

From the information from `mask`, I would like to pack integers which satisfy `rij < sij`.
In the above example, the desired return is

```
[X, X, 192, 191],
```

where `X` means we do not care what the value is.

How do I get this result using AVX2 intrinsics?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Probably just a 16-entry lookup table of `__m128i` shuffle-control vectors for `_mm_shuffle_epi8`.  (Indexed by `_mm256_movemask_pd` of course; normally you'd want to use a compare instead of a `sij - rij` subtract, although if you also need the subtract result, you could use its sign bit instead of comparing separately into a vector of masks).

See [AVX2 what is the most efficient way to pack left based on a mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36932240)

You only need to get tricky when you have more than 4 elements.  You could save LUT space by loading with `vpmovzxbd` for `vpermilps`, but that would take 2 shuffles per compare.

---

Of course if you had AVX-512 you could do a `double` compare and use the resulting `__mmask4` or `__mmask8` with `vpcompressd` to pack 32-bit elements, but before AVX-512 you don't have this primitive operation in hardware and it's expensive to emulate.