# Using intrinsics to find next non-zero in an array

Tags: c++, performance, vectorization, sse, avx

I have an int array[10000] and I want to iterate from a certain position to find the next non-zero index. Currently I use a basic while loop:

```
while(array[i] == 0){
    pos++;
}
```

etc

I know with intrinsics I could test 4 integers for zero at a time, but is there a way to return something indicating the vector index of the "first" non-zero?

Comment: Have you tried the simple solution: [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)? Unless you want to search millions of records it's no use complicating things.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am looking for low latency so its worth it. I wouldnt bother asking if I didnt need it. Appreciate the advice- but I'm asking about intrinsics because I need the speed.

Comment: I think you're looking for the next non-zero *item*, not *index*...?

Comment: @CiaPan no the index the item was found at.

Comment: And you *have* benchmarked your current (and other) solutions? Unless you're coding for a very old or slow computer looping over just 10000 items is quite fast on a modern multi-GHz machine.

Comment: Ok, you need an index, anyway it's an *item* which has to be non-zero. :) IMHO if your array is not very sparse, you shouldn't worry about sequential testing. But if it is, maybe you should consider applying some special data structure for effective handling sparse tables?

Comment: your array is pretty small, but if it were bigger, you could save time on a multi-core machine by spawning a few threads to search it.

Comment: @RedAlert I did wonder at what point using multiple threads would be advantageous.

Comment: at whatever point the overhead of creating new threads is less than what it takes to find the next non-zero in your array. When exactly that is, depends on the size & distribution of your array.

Comment: Optimizing for wide instruction/comparison (like Haswell AVX2) makes sense only if you are confident that the data is in the cache, the virtual pages are in the TLB, and the array is sparse enough.  If you end up getting a TLB miss or cache miss (hundreds of cycles to resolve) then which instruction you use to load and compare doesn't really matter.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172102/using-c-intel-assembly-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-test-if-a-128-byte-memory-blo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly simple to do this, but throughput improvement may not be great, since you will probably be limited by memory bandwidth (unless your array is already cached):

```
int index = -1;
for (i = 0; i < n; i += 4)
{
    __m128i v = _mm_load_si128(&A[i]);
    __m128i vcmp = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(v, _mm_setzero_si128());
    int mask = _mm_movemask_epi8(vcmp);
    if (mask != 0xffff)
    {
        break;
    }
}
if (i < n)
{
    for (j = i; j < i + 4; ++j)
    {
        if (A[j] != 0)
        {
             index = j;
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that the array `A` is 16 byte aligned, its size, `n`, is a multiple of 4, and that the ints are 32 bits.

Loop unrolling by a factor of 2 may help, particularly if your input data is large and/or sparse, e.g.

```
int index = -1;
for (i = 0; i < n; i += 8)
{
    __m128i v0 = _mm_load_si128(&A[i]);
    __m128i v1 = _mm_load_si128(&A[i + 4]);
    __m128i vcmp0 = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(v0, _mm_setzero_si128());
    __m128i vcmp1 = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(v1, _mm_setzero_si128());
    int mask0 = _mm_movemask_epi8(vcmp0);
    int mask1 = _mm_movemask_epi8(vcmp1);
    if ((mask0 | mask1) != 0xffff)
    {
        break;
    }
}
if (i < n)
{
    for (j = i; j < i + 8; ++j)
    {
        if (A[j] != 0)
        {
             index = j;
             break;
        }
    }
}
```

If you have AVX2 (Haswell and later) then you can process 8 ints at a time rather than 4.

Comment: Could use a while loop and mask as the continuation condition?

Comment: I don't think it would make much difference, but go ahead and try it.

Comment: @PaulR, good answer, but I don't see how unrolling will help.  There is no dependency chain (such as an accumulator).

Comment: It depends on the CPU and the compiler (and compiler switches) but in my experience small loops often benefit from 2x unrolling, if it's done intelligently. Note that this also allows you to amortize the cost of the mask test and branch. I'll post an unrolled example if that's not clear and you can try both if you like.

Comment: @PaulR, I think the unrolled version is different than what the out of order unit would do.  So it could help.  Out of order could start the next test but if that test failed before it finished the previous test it would have to wait for the previous one to finish whereas with the unroll it would bail with either one.  I guess the conditional test is a kind of dependency chain.  Just not the way I'm used to thinking about it.

Comment: Well even without the merged test, unrolling the loop can still help to hide some load latency.

Comment: Which header file defines the "_mm_load_epi32" method?. I cannot find it.

Comment: @warunapww: sorry - that's just a convenience macro that I use - it corresponds to `_mm_load_si128` - answer updated.

Comment: Your solution is fast only when there are very few nonzero elements. I guess even if there are only 10% of them, you'll already have performance problems. On the other hand, stream compaction can be done on SSE without branches by `_mm_shuffle_epi8` combined with LUT, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6270641/556899). If there a many nonzero elements, it would help.

Comment: @stgatilov: yes, I was assuming that the array is fairly sparse - I should probably have made that clearer in the answer.