# split string assembly AT&T

Tags: assembly

How do I split a string by `,` delimeter in assembly AT&T?

This is the string I have: 6, 3, 2431, 7, 9, 1221

I want to add 1 to all the numbers between the `,`.

Result should be: `7, 4, 2432, 8, 10, 1222`

I'm working with ubuntu14 - 64bit, intel cpu and GAS compiler

Comment: The best way to do this is to write some code that will scan through the string for commas, convert the ASCII numbers into a numeric value and add whatever you want to them. If you're asking us to write this code for you, you're in the wrong place.

Comment: Is this comma delimited “string” in a source file? Passed as a pointer or on the stack? Size and type of a string element? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

pseudo code:

```
; si = input string
 di = output string
 if 0 == [si] jmp NoNumberFound
NextNumberLoop:
 rax = 0
ReadLoop:
 bl = [si] & inc si
 if 0 == bl jmp LastNumberFound
 if ',' == bl jmp CommaFound
 rax = rax*10 + (bl-'0') ; extend bl to 64b of course
 jmp ReadLoop

CommaFound:
 call StoreNumberPlusOne
 [di]=',' & inc di
 jmp NextNumberLoop

LastNumberFound:
 call StoreNumberPlusOne
NoNumberFound:
 [di]='0'
 output resulting string and exit.

StoreNumberPlusOne:
 inc rax (number+1)
 print decimal formatted rax to [di] + make di point after it
 ret
```

(di/si pointer on 64b platform are of course rsi/rdi, etc... it's just pseudo code showing algorithm, not to be taken literally)

---

Other option is to do it in string itself without parsing numbers.

Allocate large enough buffer for resulting string (if you put input as `n` times `9`, the output buffer will be almost twice as long as input buffer, containing `n` times `10`).

Copy input string to outputBuffer, and have the pointer `ptr` at the last character of it.

```
doIncrement = true
while (outputBuffer <= ptr) {
  if ',' == [ptr] {
    if doIncrement {
      move by 1 byte further everything from ptr+1 onward:
      in ASM you can do that by simple REP MOVSB, but as the
      source overlap destination, make sure you use STD (DF=1)
      together with end pointers.
      [ptr+1] = '1'
    }
    doIncrement = true
  } else {
    ; [ptr] should be between '0' to '9' (for valid input)
    if doIncrement {
      ++[ptr]
      if '9'+1 == [ptr] {
        [ptr] = '0'
      } else {
        doIncrement = false
      }
    }
  }
  --ptr;
}
```

Comment: Since x86-64 is guaranteed to have SSE2 available, I might be inclined to use `pcmpeqb` / `pmovmskb` / `bsf` to find the position of the next `,`.  You can even use SSE for string->integer (`pmaddwd` with a vector of 1, 10, 100, ... place-values).  You can do even more cool stuff with if SSSE3 pshufb is available, like [converting an IPv4 dotted-quad string to an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31683632/224132).