# Do 128bit cross lane operations in AVX512 give better performance?

Tags: performance, x86, intel, avx, avx512

In designing forward looking algorithms for AVX256, AVX512 and one day AVX1024 and considering the potential implementation complexity/cost of fully generic permutes for large SIMD width I wondered if it is better to generally keep to isolated 128bit operations even within AVX512?

Especially given that AVX had 128bit units to execute 256bit operations.

To that end I wanted to know if there was a performance difference between AVX512 permute type operations across all of the 512bit vector as opposed to permute type operations *within* each 4x128bit sub-vectors of a 512bit vector?

Comment: Are you more interested in KNL or Skylake-X?  Working on an answer for both anyway.  But generally SKX still has 1c latency for in-lane stuff, and 3c for lane crossing.  Some of the fancier AVX512BW shuffles even take multiple uops on SKX, like `vpermt2w`.

Comment: I am more interested on future planning regards high end general consumer orientated desktop CPU's - so Skylake X.  Thanks.

Comment: @PeterCordes: interested to know where you got the info on AVX512BW uops on SKX ? I haven’t seen any tables from Agner Fog yet - do you have another source ?

Comment: @PaulR: Instlatx64 often has test numbers before Agner.

Comment: @PeterCordes: ah yes - thanks - I'd forgotten about that one. I'm wondering if IACA might also be helpful for this kind of thing (assuming it's up to date with Skylake X etc).

Comment: @PaulR: IACA2.3 has SKX but not KNL :/  Instlat made a spreadsheet of the uop counts / port assignments from IACA for SKX.  (See my answer)  IACA's pipeline-trace log output could give you latencies, but I assume that would match what Intel published separately in PDF form.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to limit data-movement even if it's within a register. Ever since Haswell, all 64-bit lane crossing operations that weren't a load/store are limited to port5. And all 128-bit lane crossing operations have 3 cycle latency instead of 1. I don't see this changing in the future as data movement is very expensive in terms of routing traffic.

Comment: Given the sheer number of issues with AVX512 atm, I don't see AVX1024 being a thing for at least a decade (if ever). By comparison, the introduction of AVX had relatively few issues. The EVEX encoding also leaves no room for 1024-bit versions of some features like embedded rounding unless they resort to abusing opcodes. So if it ever happens, it's likely Intel will change the encoding (yet again).

Comment: The AVX1024 comments are really interesting, as I thought it was expected to show up in the next 5 years then hit a wall (And the instruction encoding fiasco that Agner tried to warn them against).  What are the AVX512 issues you mention? Down clocking, complexity, practicality of the performance of the instructions, actually getting a CPU with support?

Comment: @iam 1) It was delayed at least year and it still isn't readily available. 2) There needs to be a better way to power gate the AVX512. You can't have a single instruction mess up the clocks for the entire application and/or system. 3) There's not enough memory bandwidth to support it. - This is all not including the usual development overhead of actually using it. But that's a common to all the ISA extensions.

Comment: The power-gating/downclocking issue is thing is biggest problem right now as it prevent people from "gradually" shifting to AVX512. It only takes a single AVX512 instruction to mess up the clock for the entire core for some long duration (milliseconds). So if the compiler inserts an AVX512 `memcpy()`, you're basically screwed. That said, compilers now are starting to catch on to this and are starting make some effort to avoid 512-bit instructions even when targeting AVX512.

Comment: The memory bandwidth issue is the next hurtle as it will affect nearly all applications that have a large memory footprint. Current processors are already bandwidth-starved with AVX. So performance scaling to AVX512 sucks. OTOH, applications that use no memory will be competing with GPUs. So unless Intel can get their memory bandwidth up (much much higher clocks + more memory channels), AVX512 is going to be difficult to utilize to full benefit. However, I don't see Intel making any efforts to improve the bandwidth situation as it seems to be going in the opposite direction.

Comment: I thought that memory bandwidth is one area that Intel had vastly improved over the past 5 years but by not enough then I see!  Does that mean they are likely to greatly increase L1 cache sizes soon then to try and compensate I wonder?  Given that AVX512 was touted to help compilers vectorise every loop that's a bit worrying what you say regards compilers and 512bit instructions - I could imagine a chain of their cost benefit analysis stripping out all the benefits of 512bit instructions in such cases.

Comment: @iam Memory bandwidth has improved by roughly a factor 2 over the past 5 years thanks to DDR4. But compute power has gone up by more than 4x thanks to a combination of AVX512, 18-core chips, higher clock speeds, and better architecture. Caches sizes are another concern. They haven't grown proportionally with the vector sizes. (and they've actually shrunk in Skylake X where the L3 is so slow as to be almost useless) I would say we'd need at least another architectural generation before AVX512 is worth using for the general population that isn't hand optimizing their applications.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Generally yes, **in-lane is still lower latency on SKX** (1 cycle vs. 3), but usually **it's not worth spending extra instructions to use them** instead of the powerful lane-crossing shuffles.  However, `vpermt2w` and a couple other shuffles need multiple shuffle-port uops, so they cost as much as multiple simpler shuffles.

**Shuffle *throughput* very easily becomes a bottleneck** if you aren't careful on recent Intel CPUs (only one shuffle execution unit on port 5).  Sometimes it's even worth using two overlapping loads instead of loading once and shuffling, i.e. using an unaligned load as a shuffle, because L1D cache is fast, and so is load-port handling of unaligned loads.  (Less so with AVX512, though, especially because every unaligned 512b load is automatically a cache-line split, because vectors and cache lines are both 64 bytes.)

For 256-bit loads, one trick is to choose a load address that splits the data you care about into the two lanes, so you can use a `vpshufb` (`_mm256_shuffle_epi8`) in-lane byte shuffle to get each byte where it's needed.

There are also rotate (new in AVX512) and shift instructions (not new).  The 64-bit element size versions can move data between smaller elements if you use a shift or rotate count of 32 or 16, for example.  `vprolq zmm, zmm, 32` is 1c latency and runs on port 0 (and also port1 for the xmm/ymm versions), swapping every element with it's neighbour.  **Shifts/rotates don't compete for port 5** on SKX.

---

[For a horizontal sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86), the only real choice is what order to shuffle in.  Usually start with `extract` / `add` down to 128b, then use `__m128` shuffles (or integer shifts), instead of using `vpermd/q` for every shuffle.  Or if you want the result broadcast to all elements, use in-lane shuffles between the first few adds, and then shuffle in 128b then 256b chunks with lane-crossing shuffles.  (Shuffling in 128b chunks isn't faster than smaller granularity immediate-control shuffles like `vpermq z,z,imm8` on SKX, but that's all you need for an hsum after doing the in-lane stuff with `vshufps` or `vpermilps`.)

---

Note that **some future CPUs may split 512b ops into two 256b ops**, perhaps an E-core in some future Intel CPU.  If done like Zen 1, that could make 512-bit lane-crossing shuffles significantly more expensive.  Even `vperm2f128` on Zen1 is 8 uops, 3c lat / 3c throughput, vs. 1 uop on SKL.  In-lane shuffles obviously decompose into 1 uop per lane fairly easily, but lane-crossing doesn't.

Fortunately **Zen 4 does *not* have this downside** - 512-bit instructions are still single-uop (including ZMM shuffles like `vpermt2d`), they just occupy an execution port for longer.  This let them make a few execution units be full-width, notably shuffles.  So things like `vpermb` are as fast as on Intel, or faster like `vpermt2b` which Intel runs as 3 uops.  This implementation strategy is much better than Zen 1's, generally not creating performance potholes, and making 512-bit vectors more usable on Zen 4 for general-purpose uses than they are on Intel.  (Saving front-end bandwidth for the same amount of back-end work.)  https://uops.info/ and see [Mysticial's writeup](https://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?p=614191).

---

##### Xeon Phi (discontinued)

**On KNL, it's not lanes, it's 1-source vs. 2-source shuffles that matter**.
e.g. `vshufps dst, same,same, imm8` is half the throughput of `vpermilps dst, src, imm8`.
1-source shuffles with a vector control like `vpermd v,v,v` are still fast, though (1 source + 1 shuffle-control vector).

Even when they're only 1 uop, the 4-7c latency shuffles (2-input) have worse than 2c throughput.  I guess that means KNL's shuffle unit isn't fully pipelined.

---

**Raw data**

https://uops.info/ is the go-to for uops / latency / ports microbenchmark info these days.  Generally well-crafted microbenchmarks and detailed results that don't try to boil things down to a single number when there multiple uops and different latencies from different inputs to the ouput(s).  And no manual typos like there sometimes are in [Agner Fog's](http://agner.org/optimize/) otherwise-good instruction tables.  Agner's microarch guide is essential reading for understanding the numbers, and possible other bottlenecks like in the front-end.

When this answer was first written, https://uops.info/ didn't exist, and Agner Fog didn't yet have test results for Skylake-X (SKX) aka SKL-SP or `gcc -march=skylake-avx512`.  But there was already [InstLatx64](http://instlatx64.atw.hu/) (Instruction throughput/Latency) results, and [IACA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021337/what-is-iaca-and-how-do-i-use-it) support.  InstLatx64 has [a spreadsheet (ODS OpenOffice/LibreOffice format)](https://github.com/InstLatx64/InstLatx64/blob/90ae72a3b9ca7d0e2d66f8d77522b66ff7981a34/AVX512_SKX_PortAssign_v102_PUB.ods) combining data from IACA (just uop count and ports), and published by Intel in a PDF (throughput/latency), and from real experimental testing on real hardware (throughput/latency).  These days https://uops.info/ is pretty quick to get new microarchitectures tested, but InstLat sometimes has CPUID dumps before test results.

[Agner Fog's](http://agner.org/optimize/) instruction tables have data for Knight's Landing Xeon Phi (KNL), and there's a section about it's Silvermont-based microarchitecture in his microarch PDF.

**KNL instructions have better latency if their input is coming from the same execution unit (e.g. shuffle -> shuffle) vs. FMA -> shuffle**.  (See the note at the top of Agner's spreadsheet).  This is what the 4-7c latency numbers are about.  A transpose or something doing a chain of shuffles might see mostly the lower latency number.  (But KNL has generally high latencies, which is why it has 4-way hyperthreading
to try to hide them).

---

### SKX: Skylake-AVX512 (and probably future mainstream Intel CPUs)

All lane crossing shuffles are at best 1 uop, 3c latency, 1c throughput.  But even complex/powerful ones like 2-input `vpermt2ps` are that fast.  This includes all shuffles that shuffle whole lanes, or insert/extract 256b chunks.

All in-lane-only shuffles are 1c latency (except for the xmm version of some new-in-avx512 lane-crossing shuffles).  So use `vpshufd zmm, zmm, imm8` or `vpunpcklqdq zmm, zmm, zmm` when that's all you need.  Or `vpshufb` or `vpermilps` with a vector control input.

Like Haswell and SKL (non-avx512), **SKX can only run shuffle uops on port 5**.  Again like those earlier CPUs, it can broadcast-load using only the load ports, so that's just as cheap as a regular vector load.  AVX512 broadcast loads can micro-fuse, making memory-source broadcasts cheaper (in shuffle throughput terms) than register source.

Even `vmovsldup ymm, [mem]` / `vmovshdup ymm, [mem]` use just a load uop for the 256b shuffle.  IDK about 512b; Instlat didn't test memory-source movsl/hdup, so we only have Agner Fog's data.  (And IIRC I confirmed that on my own SKL).

Note that when running 512b instructions, the vector ALUs on port 1 are disabled, so you have a max throughput of 2 vector ALU uops per clock.  (But p1 can still run integer stuff.)  And vector load/store uops don't need p0 / p5, so you can still bottleneck on the front-end (4 uops per clock issue/rename) in code with a mix of non-fused loads, stores, and ALU (and integer loop overhead, and vmovdqa register copying handled in the rename stage with unfused-domain uop).

Exceptions to the rule on SKX:

- `VPMOVWB ymm, zmm` and similar truncate or signed/unsigned saturate instructions are 2 uops, 4c latency.  (Or 2c for the xmm versions).  `vpmovqd` is 1 uop, 3c (or 1c xmm) latency, because its smallest granularity is dword and it's only truncating, not saturating, so it can be implemented internally with the same hardware that's needed for `pshufb` for example.  `vpmovz/sx` instructions are still only 1 uop.
- `vpcompressd/q` (left-pack based on a mask) is 2 uops (p5), 3c latency.  (Or 6c according to what Intel publishes; maybe Instlat is testing the vector->vector latency and Intel is giving the `k` register -> vector latency?  Unlikely that it's data-dependent and faster with a trivial mask.)  `vpexpandd` is also 2 uops.
- AVX512BW **`vpermt2w` / `vpermi2w` is 3 uops (p0 + 2p5)**, 7c latency for all 3 operand sizes (xmm/ymm/zmm).  Small-granularity wide shuffles are expensive in hardware (See [Where is VPERMB in AVX2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980209/where-is-vpermb-in-avx2) including the comments).  This is a 2-source 16-bit-element shuffle with the control in a 3rd vector.  It might get faster eventually in future generations, the way `pshufb` (and all full-register shuffles with granularity smaller than 8 bytes) [was slow in first-gen Core2 Conroe/Merom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86), but got fast in the die-shrink next generation (Penryn).
- AVX512BW **`vpermw`** (one-source lane-crossing word shuffle) is 2p5, 6c latency, 2c throughput because it's a lane-crossing word shuffle.
- expect [AVX512VBMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512) `vpermt2b` to be as bad or worse on Cannonlake, even if Cannonlake does improve `vpermt2w` / `vpermw`.
- `vpermt2d/q/ps/pd` are all efficient in SKX because their granularity is dword (32-bit) or wider.  (But still apparently 3c latency for the xmm version, so they didn't build separate hardware to speed up the one-lane version).  These are even more powerful than a lane-crossing `shufps`: a variable control and with no limitation on which source register each element comes from.  It's a *fully* general 2-source shuffle where you index into the concatenation of 2 registers, overwriting the index (`vpermi2*`) or one of the tables (`vpermt2*`).  There's only one intrinsic because the compiler handles register allocation and copying to preserve still-needed values.

---

### Knight's Landing:

Shuffles run on the FP0 port only, but front-end throughput is only 2 uops per clock.  So more of your total instructions can be shuffles without bottlenecking on that (vs. SKX), unless they're half-throughput shuffles.

In general, 2-input shuffles like `vperm2f128`/`vshuff32x4` or `vshufps` are 2c throughput / 4-7c latency, while 1-input shuffles like `vpermd` are 1c throughput / 3-6c latency.  (i.e. 2 inputs occupies the shuffle unit for an extra cycle (half throughput) and costs 1 extra cycle of latency).  Agner isn't clear on exactly what the effect of the not-fully-pipelined shuffles is, but I assume it just ties up the shuffle unit, and not everything on port FP0 (like the FMA unit).

- Lane-crossing or not makes no difference on KNL, e.g. `vpermilps` and `vpermps` are both fast (1c throughput, 3-6c latency), but `vpermi2ps` and `vshufps` are both slow (2c throughput, 4-7c latency).  I don't see any exceptions to that for instructions where KNL supports an AVX512 version.  (i.e. not counting AVX2 `vpshufb`, i.e. pretty much anything with 32-bit or larger granularity).
- **`vinserti32x4` and so on** (insert/extract with granularity of at least 128b) is a 2-input shuffle for insert, but is fast: 3-6c lat / 1c tput.  But extract-to-memory is multiple uops and causes a decode bottleneck: e.g. `VEXTRACTF32X4 m128,z` is 4 uops, one per 8c throughput.  (mostly because of decode).
- `vcompress/ps/d`, `vpcompressd/q` and `v[p]expandd/q/ps/pd` are 1 uop, 3-6c latency.  (vs. 2 uops on SKX).  But throughput is only one per 3c: Agner doesn't indicate whether this ties up the whole shuffle unit for 2c, or if only this part is not fully pipelined.
- AVX2 byte/word shuffles are very slow for 256b operand-size: `pshufb xmm` is 5 uops / 10c throughput, `vpshufb ymm` is 12 uops / 12c throughput.  (MMX `pshufb mm` is 1 uop, 2-6c latency, 1c throughput, so I guess the byte-granularity shuffle unit is 64b wide.)

  `pshuflw xmm` is 1 uop fast, but `vpshuflw ymm` is 4 uops, 8c throughput.

  Video encoding on KNL might be barely worth it with 128-bit AVX (`vpsadbw xmm` is fast), but AVX2 ymm instructions are generally slower than using more 1 uop xmm instructions.
- `movss/sd xmm,xmm` is a blend, not a shuffle, and has 0.5c throughput / 2c latency.
- vpunpcklbw / wd are super slow (except the xmm version), but DQ and QDQ are the regular speed even for ymm / zmm operand size.  (2c throughput / 4-7c latency, because it's a 2-input shuffle).
- `vpmovzx` is 3c latency (not 3-6c?) and 2c throughput even for `vpmovzxbw`.  `vpmovsx` is slower: 2 uops and thus a decode bottleneck, making it 8c latency and 7c throughput.  The narrowing truncate instructions (`vpmovqb` and so on) are 1 uop, 3c lat / 1c tput, but the narrowing saturate instructions are 2 uops and thus slow.  Agner didn't test them with a memory destination.

Comment: This is a really amazing answer. Maybe mystical's comment of "It's generally a good idea to limit data-movement.." forms the basis for a good summary at the end?

Comment: Ok the highlighting works fine to stop my brain skimming the start :)

Comment: @iam: added some more general performance background stuff, good idea to try to give some general advice.  e.g. sometimes you can use more unaligned loads and fewer shuffles.

Comment: Thank you - extremely helpful as currently planning how to expand working 128bit based vector code to 256bit and beyond.  Where current bottleneck is data shuffling/permute/gather related and I have concerns regard algorithm granularity in conjunction with that.

Comment: The link to "spreadsheet (ODS OpenOffice/LibreOffice format)" is broken

Comment: I managed to find a copy on their github mirror here, maybe you can update your answer (I'll propose the edit): https://github.com/InstLatx64/InstLatx64/blob/90ae72a3b9ca7d0e2d66f8d77522b66ff7981a34/AVX512_SKX_PortAssign_v102_PUB.ods

Comment: @Y00: Thanks.  These days I look at https://uops.info/ for better / more detailed test results for latency, ports, and throughput; it didn't exist when this was written.  I had a look at that AIDA InstLat spreadsheet, and one difference I noticed is that they measured only 0.48c throughput for vpternlogd for widths less than zmm.  But this is not a case where Intel's own published results are wrong.  uops.info correctly found it running on p015 at 0.33c, using a microbenchmark that didn't bottleneck on latency unlike apparently InstLat.

Comment: Zen4 has been released with AVX512 and shuffles are fine on that, please update

Comment: @CalculatorFeline: Thanks, done.  AMD did much better with AVX-512 in Zen 4 than they did with AVX / AVX2 in Zen 1 (saving front-end bandwidth by just double-pumping the ALUs), and the single-uop ZMM shuffles are great.