# Is there an SIMD instruction to achieve batch array memory index mapping?

Tags: sse, simd, neon

In my RGB to grey case:

```
Y = (77*R + 150*G + 29*B) >> 8;
```

I know SIMD (NEON, SSE2) can do like:

```
foreach 8 elements:
{A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7} = 77*{R0,R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7}
{B0,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7} = 150*{G0,G1,G2,G3,G4,G5,G6,G7}
{C0,C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7} = 29*{B0,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7}
{D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7} = {A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7} + {B0,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7}
{D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7} = {D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7} + {C0,C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7}
{D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7} = {D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7} >> 8
```

However, the multiply instruction take at least 2 clock cycles, and R,G,B in [0-255], 
we can use three lookup table(an array, length=256) to store the partial result of 
77*R(mark as X), 150*G(mark as Y), 29*B(mark as Z).
So I'm looking for instructions can do the intention:

```
foreach 8 elements:
{A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7} = {X[R0],X[R1],X[R2],X[R3],X[R4],X[R5],X[R6],X[R7]}
{B0,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7} = {Y[G0],Y[G1],Y[G2],Y[G3],Y[G4],Y[G5],Y[G6],Y[G7]}
{C0,C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7} = {Z[B0],Z[B1],Z[B2],Z[B3],Z[B4],Z[B5],Z[B6],Z[B7]}
{D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7} = {A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7} + {B0,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7}
{D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7} = {D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7} + {C0,C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7}
{D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7} = {D0,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7} >> 8
```

Any good suggestions?

Comment: Up to 16bit multiply on NEON consumes a single cycle. (at least on ARMv7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no byte or word gather instructions in AVX2 / AVX512, and no gathers at all in NEON.  The DWORD gathers that do exist are much slower than a multiply!  e.g. one per 5 cycle throughput for `vpgatherdd ymm,[reg + scale*ymm], ymm`, according to [Agner Fog's instruction table for Skylake](http://agner.org/optimize/).

You can use shuffles as a parallel table-lookup.  But your table for each lookup is 256 16-bit words.  That's 512 bytes.  AVX512 has some shuffles that select from the concatenation of 2 registers, but that's "only" 2x 64 bytes, and the byte or word element-size versions of those are [multiple uops on current CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47646238/do-128bit-cross-lane-operations-in-avx512-give-better-performance).  (e.g. [AVX512BW `vpermi2w`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/VPERMI2W_D_Q_PS_PD)).  They are still fantastically powerful compared to `vpshufb`, though.

So using a shuffle as a LUT won't work in your case, but it does work *very* well for some cases, e.g. for popcount you can split bytes into 4-bit nibbles and use `vpshufb` to do 32 lookups in parallel from a 16-element table of bytes.

**Normally for SIMD you want to replace table lookups with computation, because computation is much more SIMD friendly.**

---

Suck it up and use [`pmullw` / `_mm_mullo_epi16`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/PMULLW).  You have instruction-level parallelism, and Skylake has 2 per clock throughput for 16-bit SIMD multiply (but 5 cycle latency).  For image processing, normally throughput matters more than latency, as long as you keep the latency within reason so out-of-order execution can hide it.

If your multipliers ever have few enough `1` bits in their binary representation, you could consider using shift/add instead of an actual multiply.  e.g. `B * 29 = B * 32 - B - B * 2`.  Or `B<<5 - B<<1 - B`.  That many instructions probably has more throughput cost than a single multiply, though.  If you could do it with just 2 terms, it might be worth it.  (But then again, still maybe not, depending on the CPU.  Total instruction throughput and vector ALU bottlenecks are a big deal.)