# _mm256_permutexvar_epi8 and _mm256_permutexvar_epi16 AVX2 equivalents for compile-time-constant shuffles?

Tags: c++, simd, avx2, avx512

I am looking for a way to ***permutate the 1 byte and/or 2 byte*** values in an `__m256i` register using AVX2 instructions. The solution needs to be able to able ***move values across 128-bit lanes***.

I know that with AVX512 I could use `_mm256_permutexvar_epi8` and `_mm256_permutexvar_epi16` but I cant seem to find any generic solution with AVX2 for when the values need to go across lanes (if the values can stay within lane `_mm256_shuffle_epi8` or `_mm256_shuflehi_epi16(_mm256_shufflelo_epi16)` works).

The permutation indices will be known at compile time.

Comment: You can't do it in one instruction, that's why `vpermb` requires AVX512VBMI.  [Where is VPERMB in AVX2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37980209).  If you need a fully-general thing that works for any runtime-variable vector, you'll have to emulate it with maybe 2x `_mm256_shuffle_epi8` and a blend, or something like that. (You'd have to lane-swap the input for one `vpshufb` with `vpermq` or something, so that's at least 3 shuffles).  Otherwise hopefully you can do something more efficient.

Comment: Any improvements if the permutation vector is known at compile time (but could be anything)?

Comment: `_mm256_shuflehi_epi16` is `vpshufhw`, and only works for immediate constants.  You can't emulate runtime-variable byte shuffles with it.  If your shuffle is a compile-time constant, again you should be looking at doing something more clever.  **Agner Fog's VCL has some template metaprogramming to try to find efficient ways to to implement arbitrary shuffles.**  https://github.com/vectorclass/version2

Comment: I see. Should have checked that earlier. Thank you!

Comment: Since the permutation in known at compile time, if you're using GCC or clang you can use `__builtin_shuffle` (GCC) or `__builtin_shufflevector` (clang).  They generally do a very good job selecting the best instructions.

Comment: @nemequ this is great. Clang has this really optimized (gcc appears to be missing a few cases).

Comment: @Noah, if you want an abstraction that works on both compilers, feel free to steal https://github.com/simd-everywhere/simde/blob/master/simde/simde-common.h#L302-L326 (the file is MIT, but if you need it under a different license let me know; that macro is exclusively my fault so I can give you a license under other terms).