# Storage and String manipulation in x86 Assembly Language

Tags: string, assembly, x86

I've just picked up learning assembly language coding.

Q: Convert a character string that represents any signed integer to its 2’s complement value, with the result stored in consecutive locations of memory in little endian order.

For example - 1 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE assuming 2's complement codewards are 64-bit. I've done the number -149 in my code which should result in
 0xffff ffff ffff ff6b

```
            .data
S:  .string "-149"
Result:     .quad

            .text
            .globl main

main: 
    mov     S,%rax
    cmp     %rax,0
    jl      positive
    sub     %rax,%rax
    not     S
    add     S,%rax
    sub     $30,%rax
    not     %rax
    add     $1, %rax
    mov     %rax,Result

positive:
    sub     $30,%rax
    not     %rax
    add     $1,%rax 
    mov     %rax,Result
```

In GDB, the value for the string integer stored is this.

```
(gdb) x/24xb &S
0x601038:   0x2d    0x31    0x34    0x39    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x601040:   0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x601048:   0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
```

if I wanted to do any computations to -149, I'd have to somehow access these locations in the memory - how do I go about doing this?

If I know that the 4 is in the 10's place, I could multiply it by 10 to get 40 and then add the 9 and similiar 1x100 to get 100 and add that as well.

How do I access them to do the computation?

Comment: It seems you haven't nailed the other part too. We can't answer debug questions here, please clarify what the exact problem is. The part about consecutive "locations" is effectively unclear: x86 are little endian and depending on the size, in bits, of the numbers that you have to handle, that request may just translate to a store into memory.

Comment: Thanks Margaret, specifically I'm wondering about how to apply logical/arithmetic operations to a .string stored signed integer value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I access them to do the computation?

A string is stored as consecutive characters in memory.  If it's ASCII (not UTF-8), each character is a single byte.

So you can access them one at a time with byte loads/stores, like `movzbl 2(%rsi), %eax` to get the 3rd character, if `rsi` points to the start of the string.

Or, if `%rdi` points to the last character (the ones place in a decimal number), then `imul  $10, -1(%rdi), %ecx` will set `%cl` to the second-last character plus its place-value.  (And the upper bytes of `%ecx` to garbage; it's probably better to do a `movzx` load first and then a multiply.  This [does work, though, to get the low 8 bits correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377711/which-2s-complement-integer-operations-can-be-used-without-zeroing-high-bits-in)).

At the other end of the complexity spectrum, have a look at this [SSE4.1 IPv4 dotted-quad string to 32bit integer converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31683632/224132).  Specifically, the decimal place-value part after the shuffle, using `pmaddubsw`  (`_mm_maddubs_epi16`) with a vector of `[ ..., 100, 10, 1 ]` to apply the place-value and one step of horizontal adding, then `phaddw` to horizontally add the up-to-three digits from each dotted quad.

Also [How to implement atoi using SIMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127060/how-to-implement-atoi-using-simd)

See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for lots of other links.

Comment: Yes: "If it's ASCII (not UTF-8)…" You can't take a specification on string values without requiring it to specify the character set and encoding. @Egyptian_Coder Send it back.

Comment: @TomBlodget: In an asm homework assignment, you can assume ASCII.  In this specific case, it's supposed to be a decimal number, which means it definitely is the ASCII subset of UTF-8.  I wrote that sentence as a warning that the "normal" (easy) way of addressing strings assumes one byte per char, not as a suggestion that he should find out if he needs to actually handle UTF-8 in asm.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I expect this will not even compile (for example `cmp %rax,0` is not a valid combination in AT&T syntax, this looks like you would want Intel syntax).

And there are some things which don't make any sense, like `not S` ... what do you think that would do? If you would annotate it as byte ptr, it would invert the '<' character (actually why do you have '<' and '>' in the S string is confusing me too).

etc, etc...

So first try to compile it, then open it in debugger, step instruction by instruction, and keep looking at CPU registers and memory and instruction reference guide... till it will makes sense... may take some time, but actually not that long maybe, few days and you will get hang of it.

Comment: `cmp %rax, 0` is a compare with an absolute addressing mode.  `cmp` is available with a memory operand as the first or second operand, so that should assemble, but not to what the OP probably wanted.

Comment: Please don't pollute the site with generic answers. Either provide a full one, comment the question or flag it as unanswerable.