# compare vector of values using intrinsics / simd

Tags: c, simd, intrinsics, avx

I'm trying to compare a vector of 8 bit chars to another vector using intrinsics, but encountering an unexpected crash when comparing values. I'm using C/C++ with microsoft visual studio for this. A minimum reproducable example would be the following:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Below is longer than 32 bytes so should be enough for an example.
    std::string input = "AEHAICIAAAAAAAAFJIAOEJFEJAIJEJRIAJEJIJRIAJIEJRIAJIEJRAIJIERJAIEJA";
    const char* input_c = input.c_str();
    auto loadedA = _mm256_set_epi8('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A','A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A');
    auto loaded32 = _mm256_loadu_si256((const __m256i*) input_c);
    // Crash below this line
    auto cmpA = _mm256_mask_cmp_epi8_mask((__mmask32) 0xffffffff, loaded32, loadedA, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Specific question: Is there a fix / alternative instruction I could use that would have similar behaviour? I need to be able to compare 8 bit values.

Edit: The instruction that compiles from  _mm256_mask_cmp_epi8_mask was not supported by my CPU. I solved the issue by using _mm256_cmpeq_epi8 instead.
Duplicate: [Comparing 2 vectors in AVX/AVX2 (c)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243456/comparing-2-vectors-in-avx-avx2-c)

Comment: You should give more details about this crash (debugging details). Error message? Stack trace? Also, you should consider including a proper question.

Comment: @F.Müller The debugger says the code tries to execute an illegal instruction (vpcmpb  k1,ymm0,ymmword ptr [rbp+80h],0). Although I thought this was available to me. I'm using an Intel i7-8550U atm.

Comment: Kaby Lake (your CPU) doesn't have AVX512 (`_mm256_mask_cmp_epi8_mask` aka `vpcmpb`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check all bytes of a \_\_m128i for a match of a single byte using SSE/AVX/AVX2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897297/check-all-bytes-of-a-m128i-for-a-match-of-a-single-byte-using-sse-avx-avx2)  Obvious extention to `__m256i` and a constant vector to compare against

Comment: @harold That does not answer my question, but it turns out another duplicate question did solve my issue. How do I mark this thread as duplicate?

Comment: It's already done. And the various choices for duplicates all look kind of same-y to me, `vpcmpeqb` and `vpmovmskb` (which maybe you don't need, depends on what the next step is) in combination with various small extras

Comment: @harold The 2nd option checks if any value in the vector is equal to a certain value. I would like a result vector that tells for each specific element if it is equal which is what the 1st option provides. The 3rd option doesn't seem related to what I'm trying to do as it seems to deal with converting values instead of doing a comparison. My question seems to be specifically a duplicate of the 1st option. I thought only I could see the options so far because I saw "(Private feedback for you)" in the box.