# what is the use of MOVMSKB operation?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, sse, instruction-set

I want to ask what is the use for `MOVMSKB` operation?

I try to find the documentation, but I cannot find the information related.

Comment: there is `PMOVMSKB` did you mean it ? https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmovmskb

Comment: no, I can find `PMOVMSKB` and `MOVMSKPS` `MOVMSKPD`but I cannot find `MOVMSKB` which is what I am looking for.

Comment: The is no instruction named `MOVMSKB` in the Intel ISA.

Comment: Why do you think there is a `MOVMSKB` instruction separate from `PMOVMSKB`?  There isn't, so perhaps your real question should be about how to interpret whatever you were reading?  Maybe the `_mm_movemask_epi8` intrinsic?  And BTW, the use-cases for `pmovmskb` include search loops like `strlen` or `memchr`, as well as an index for a lookup table of `pshufb` masks e.g. for left-packing, or parsing IPv4 dotted-quad strings into integers.

Comment: That instruction is mentioned in a paper, [link](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/768.pdf)(just above section 5.2) @PeterCordes

Answer (score 1):

The [paper you're reading](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/768.pdf) describes in the next sentence exactly what it does:

> This instruction creates a 16-bit
>   mask from the most significant bits of 16 signed or unsigned
>   8-bit integers in a register and zeroes the upper bits [of the destination]

That's *exactly* what [`pmovmskb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmovmskb) does on an XMM register, so obviously that's the instruction they're talking about.  They intentionally or accidentally left out the `p` (for packed-integer) from the mnemonic.

Their diagram of how it works is (incorrectly) labeled with `vpmovmskb reg, ymm1`.  With a YMM source, `vpmovmskb` produces a 32-bit mask.

(Although if the input YMM register has been written via the XMM low half with a VEX-encoded instruction like `vpxor xmm1, xmm2, xmm3`, then the upper 16 bytes would be all zero, so they'd get the result they described for a different reason.)

---

Its use-cases include include search loops like `strlen` or `memchr` (where `lzcnt` / `tzcnt` are useful to find which element once you find a match or mismatch element).

Or creating an index for a lookup table of `pshufb` masks e.g. for left-packing, or even as part of parsing IPv4 dotted-quad strings into integers.  [Fastest way to get IPv4 address from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679341/fastest-way-to-get-ipv4-address-from-string)